# C# | Creating Multiple Threads with a for-loop, doing kinda different tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading

Main

```
foreach(Thread t in createTestThreads(8)) {
                t.Start();
            }
```

```
private static Thread[] createTestThreads(int ThreadCount) {
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[ThreadCount];
            for(int i = 0; i < ThreadCount; i++) {
                Thread t = new Thread(() => {
                    Console.Write(i);
                });
                threads[i] = t;
            }
            return threads;
        }
```

Wished Result:
01234567
(Probably not in that exact order, but doesn't have to be)
Actual Result:
88888888
Is there any other way of doing this without naming the Threads manually t0, t1, t2, etc.. Like is there a way to create Threads with dynamical names for example Thread ("t" + i) = new Thread (() =>

Comment: Does Parallel list a solution for you?

Comment: The result you get is caused by the fact that lambda in C# captures a variable, not a value. What is your actual question, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The dupe question is a bit long but the answer applies here directly.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is captured in your lambda; you need to copy it to a temporary variable:

```cs
for(int i = 0; i < ThreadCount; i++)
{
    int ii = i; // copy value of i to temp variable
    Thread t = new Thread(() => 
    { 
        Console.Write(ii); }); 
        threads[ii] = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is a new contributor, I think getting him to describe his objectives clearly so he can receive and appropriate support would be better than providing a suitable answer based on his question. why is he trying to create so much thread that could be catastrophic?

Comment: @codein, agreed, and will follow your advice in the future (as this post has been closed as a duplicate anyhow). Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to create one child thread to the main thread. 
The main thread calls the sub-class createTestThreads and send argument

```
createTestThreads(8)
```

The class initialize a thread

```
    Thread threads = new Thread(()=> job(8));
    threads.Start();
```

A method in the class called job

```
Public void job(int limit)
{
        private void job(int ThreadCount)
        {
            for(int i= 0; i < ThreadCount; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        } 
}
```

This however only initialize one child thread, are you interested in initializing 8 child threads?

Comment: Your code won't compile.